# Expression of double summation in python

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, pulp

I am trying to solve an optimization problem using Pulp in Python, but I'm having some trouble in expressing my constraints.

```
def Kakuro(M):
    prob = pulp.LpProblem() 
    rows = range(1,4)
    cols = range(1,4)
    vals = range(1,10)

    X = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("X",(rows,cols,vals),cat='Binary')

    for i in rows:
        for j in cols:
            prob += sum([X[i][j][k] for k in vals]) == 1
            
    for i in rows:
        for k in vals:
            prob += sum([X[i][j][k] for j in cols]) == M[i][0] #This is expressing x_111+x_121+x_131=M[i]; x_112+x_122+x_132=M[i]...

    for j in cols:
        for k in vals:
            prob += sum([X[i][j][k] for i in rows]) == M[0][j]

    prob.solve() #prob.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=0))

    solution = np.zeros((4,4))
    for i in rows:
      solution[i][0] = M[i][0]
    for j in cols:
      solution[0][j]=M[0][j]

    for i in rows:
        for j in cols:
            for k in vals:
                if X[i][j][k].value() == 1:
                    solution[i,j] = k
    
    return solution
```

For the second and third for-loop, what I want to say is Equation like
`x_{111}+x_{121}+x_{131}+x_{112}+ ... +x_{119}+x_{129}+x_{139}=M[i][0]`,
but now it is `x_111+x_121+x_131=M[i][0]`. How can I have 2 loops inside the prob equation?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you can just augment the summation expression to include 2 variables...  Something like:

```
for i in cols:
    prob += sum(x[i][j][k] for j in rows for k in vals) <= M[i][0]
```